# How setInterval() function works?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

After we put this function into a variable in order to be able to use `clearInterval()`, why it works without calling this function?

Usually, when we put a function into a variable, in order to fire it we should call it. In this example, I thought it should have worked like in the code below, but it works without calling it.

```js
let time = 0;

var timer = setInterval(() => {
  window.console.log(`Time passed: ${time}`);
  time = time + 1;

  if (time > 5) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);

timer();
```

Comment: You are calling `setInterval` and you are storing reference returned by `setInterval` to `timer` variable.

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your issue, then you should mark the answer that best helped you as correct. This will help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It would have worked as you expected if you were actually putting a function in the `timer` variable but you are not. You are calling `setInterval` function and storing its return value into the `timer` variable.

In order for it to work as you expect it to, you need to put it inside another function like this:

```js
let time = 0;

var timer = function() {
  return setInterval(() => {
    window.console.log(`Time passed: ${time}`);
    time = time + 1;

    if (time > 5) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

timer();
```

Now, calling `timer()` will invoke the timer as you expect.

Comment: `clearInterval(timer);` will not clear the interval because `timer` is a function not the return value of `setInterval`.

Comment: Well, yes. The return value of the `timer()` call needs to be stored in a separate variable which later can be used to clear the interval.

Answer (score 0):

The `clearInterval()` function in JavaScript clears the interval which has been set by the `setInterval()` function before that.

- `setInterval()` function takes two arguments. The first one was the function that is to be executed and the second argument was a time (in ms).
- `setInterval()` executes the passed function for the given time interval. The number id value returned by `setInterval()` function is stored in a variable and it’s passed into the `clearInterval()` function to clear the interval.

```js
let time = 0;

let timer = function() {
  return setInterval(() => {
    window.console.log(`Time passed: ${time}`);
    time = time + 1;

    if (time > 5) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your setInterval to a function.

```js
let time = 0;

var timer = () => setInterval(() => {
  console.log(`Time passed: ${time}`);
  time = time + 1;
  if (time > 5) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);

timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the current answers fully explains the issues with your code. I see three issues with your code.

You said this in your question:

> Usually, when we put a function into a variable, in order to fire it we should call it

This is true. When a variable has a function as its value, you must call the variable/function in order to run it. However, the variable `timer` in your code is not a function. You passed a function to the `setInterval()` function, which then returns an ID number that can be passed to `clearInterval()` later on. In your code, `timer` is set to this ID number returned by `setInterval()`. The function is never in your variable because it is wrapped by a `setInterval()` call.

To fix this, change `timer` to a function, and change its name to something like `makeTimer()` because it creates a new timer. Inside your function, you can set a new variable (let's call it `id`) to the ID number that `setInterval()`. You can then pass `id` to `clearInterval()`.

Your code has another problem though. You initialize the `time = 0`, so that when your function is first called by `setInterval()`, it prints `"Time passed: 0"`. However, `setInterval()` first runs your function *after* 1000 milliseconds pass for the first time, so really 1 second has already passed, not 0. To fix this, just initialize `time = 1` instead.

A few more things in your code could also be improved. Generally, global variables like your `time` variable are bad because it only needs to be inside the `makeTimer()` scope. You can also shorten your code that increments `time` and checks if `time > 5` into one line with the `++` operator. See the code below:

```js
const makeTimer = () => {
  let time = 1;
  let id = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`Time passed: ${time}`);
    if (++time > 5) clearInterval(id);
  }, 1000);
};

makeTimer();
```